# AlertDialog not showing but modal

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Have an `Activity` which has an event called method that is called on pressing **Enter** or tapping on an onscreen button. In this event I build an `AlertDialog` if some criteria is met.

```
public void process() {
    ....
    final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    adb.setTitle(getString(R.string.alert_title));
    adb.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_question));
    adb.setCancelable(false);
    adb.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.alert_answer_ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            ....
        }
    });
    adb.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.alert_answer_no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            ....
        }
    });
    adb.show();
    ....
}
```

However, running in the emulator, when the event fires, the `AlertDialog` does not show up:
It blocks the `Activity` like there is a modal dialog above it, but the dialog itself is not visible.

What does cause this? How can I show the dialog properly?

### EDIT

Tried this, too, but still does not work:

```
adb.create().show();
```

Comment: Its not clear what you'r saying

Comment: The `Activity` is blocking, does not response to taps, not even to hardware back button, but the dialog is not visible.

Comment: I believe you are passing wrong context ,try "ClassName.this" instead of only "this",you need UI threads Context usually MainActivity

Comment: `this` is tha same as `*Activity.this` in this case. Tried that, too. But no change at all... Also tried `getActivity()`...

Comment: When the method `process` is called? What is thread?

Comment: It is called on 3rd party event, the calling thread is `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, I figured it out.

The problem was not with the building of the dialog, but with my method did not end with the showing of the dialog.
However, as the method was called in the UI thread, the dialog did not get drawed until this method concluded...

So I just put the code after the dialog, into a separate method, and called it in the else case of the condition that displayed the dialog, and also in the dialog buttons' listeners...

Thanks for your help, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
```

Get the AlertDialog from create()

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Check Google Doc [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: I do not see what is the difference.

Comment: You need to create it by builder.create(); 
Hope it solve probleam

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder.show()` is creating it, see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#show()

Comment: Yes, i saw. You are right but before that you need to create Dialog and then you can use show() method.

Comment: Not really understand: I "need to create Dialog" before creating the dialog?

Comment: **AlertDialog.Builder** does the settings of the attributes such as setTitle() or setMessage() and are not displayed to the user.

**AlertDialog**  is the one that displays those attributes which have been set in the AlertDialog.Builder.

The purpose of having both as mentioned somewhere is that it allows settings to be made separately from the actual displaying which in turn makes thing convenient.

Comment: As mentioned above, `AlertDialog.Builder.show()` **creates and  shows** the dialog. Writing them separatedly does not affect the problem. See my edit.

Comment: Where do you show that dialog? in which method? onCreate? please post surrounding method

Comment: It is an event called method, not Android's own event, but a user event. Can have different sources: like keypress, tap, or even hardware event (from 3rd party hardware library).